# PYQT QpushButton with QcomboBox multi-slot connect

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qcombobox, qpushbutton

So I have developed this GUI for work, but I am having trouble connecting my QcomboBox to multiple different slot, depending on user input. Essentially, I want the user to be able to select a drive from a QcomboBox, then press a QpushButton and be automatically directed to the network drive.

[image: screenshot]

I have been scratching my head over the logic for days now. I know the second part of the code should go something like this (maybe?):

```
def retranslateUi(Self, MainWindow):
    self.btnGo.clicked.connect(self.DriverSelectClicked)

def DriverSelectClicked(self):
    if self.comboBox1.currentIndex() == 0:
       os.startfile('C:/')
    if self.comboBox1.currentIndex() == 1:
       os.startfile('Z:/')
```

Comment: You should try to change from clicked signal to currentIndexChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be pulling the drive path information directly from the combobox. In addition to setting the text for a combobox entry, you can also set data

```
drives = ['C:\\', 'Z:\\']
for drive in drives:
    text = '[{}] Disk Drive'.format(drive)
    self.comboBox1.addItem(text, drive)
```

Then later, when you're processing the click, you can just read the data field that contains the drive and use that directly

```
def DriverSelectClicked(self):
    drive = self.comboBox1.itemData(self.comboBox1.currentIndex())
    if drive:
       os.startfile(drive)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ Brendan Abel! This worked perfectly.